# Creating data macro in Acces 365 which will shift a date by number field

Tags: ms-access

I have been working on a database in Access 365. I am trying to get a field filed using a the date from another field and a number from a second field. see below

[SOV].[Invoice Date] = [SOV].[Close Date] + [SOV].[Terms] where Invoice and Close are dates and Terms is a whole number.

I am trying to modify using a Data Macro but cant get the addition to work. I have tried DateAdd(), straight adding among other things. I get a message that these functions are not supported.

Anyone have any work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateSerial() to ensure that a correct date time format is returned.

Thus a expression like this in the before change event of a data macro (table macro) should work:

```
SetField
Name:   InvoiceDate
Value: =  DateSerial(Year([CloseDate]),Month([CloseDate]),Day([CloseDate])+[Terms])
```

So use dateSerial. This will allow you to add "days" to the day parameter of dateserial, and the resulting format will be a correct date format that can be suffed into the InvoiceDate.